# Hovering tag animation bug

Tags: bug, design

When the mouse enters a tag's area, it activates the animation of a growing `<div>` where it displays information regarding the tag. Then, if the mouse leaves the tag, plus the `<div>`'s area, it will vanish.

The issue is, if it activates, but the mouse leaves the area before the animation finishes, it will stay untill the mouse enters and leaves it again or if you enter another tag's area.

To make sure everyone understands, here's the **short explanation**:
Hover a [tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags) for a split second, when you see the gray form's animation starting, stop hovering it before it's done and it will stay fixed there untill you hover and leave it again or if you hover another tag.

[image: Start of the tag's animation in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags]

Comment: Same on FF 51.0 (not that easy to reproduce though)

Comment: Can I know if this is gonna be worked on or if it's not?

Comment: Probably not. This is an edge of an edge case. The workaround; hover longer.